Use a new keyboard and a new mouse on a Xubuntu 22.04.4 system
Currently I'm using a wireless keyboard/mouse set and both are communicating with the system through a small usb receiver.
I'd like to replace them with a new wired set made by a different brand. The new keyboard will be connected to a usb port on the computer and the mouse will be connected to the keyboard since the keyboard is equipped with two usb ports.
I guess that since both the current and the new sets are plug'n'play, the only thing I need to do is just disconnect the current set and connect the new one and everything will work as expected. Is this correct or is there any chance the system is going to face any problems when I switch it back on and it detects this new hardware?
Thank you.

I have changed keyboard and mouse repeatedly over 19 years and never had any problem with Ubuntu recognizing the new hardware. Never needed to reboot. Never needed "drivers". It all just worked. Every time.

@karel, my question is specific and it concerns keyboard and mouse replacement which is something that I'm sure many users have tried and know the answer already. It's not about generic device compatibility with Ubuntu. Also, the "Try it" response on the other question is exactly what I'd like to avoid if possible since I'm working on this system and I wouldn't like to do experiments with it that might cause malfunctions.

@user535733, thank you.

If you move the Bluetooth mouse out of range then it will be temporarily disconnected as if the battery had run down to 0%. I've never used a wired mouse that wasn't plug and play. Wired mice are almost always plug and play, so if you plug in a wired mouse you will be able to use it normally.
If you want to go back to using the Bluetooth mouse running bluetoothctl power on will list the MAC address of the default Bluetooth controller. If that doesn't work run the following commands.
bluetoothctl power on
bluetoothctl discoverable on
bluetoothctl pairable on
bluetoothctl list

The last command outputs information about the connected Bluetooth controllers, including their MAC addresses and what the default controller is. The default controller is the controller that will be operated on when you run a command.
If the Bluetooth mouse is a plug and play device it will connect automatically like a wired mouse. If the Bluetooth mouse is not a plug and play device you will have to configure it manually using bluetoothctl. This is where a potential problem could arise if you try to remove the Bluetooth mouse with a command of the form bluetoothctl remove XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX where XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is the mouses's MAC address. Some Bluetooth mice require a inputting PIN number to pair the mouse which you may not have (0000 is a common PIN number). For this reason it is not a good idea to manually remove a Bluetooth mouse with bluetoothctl remove

Thank you very much for the detailed information. You didn't mention wireless keyboard/mouse combos that connect through usb tranceivers though. Does this mean that those combos are always compatible the same way wired combos are?

Wireless keyboard/mouse combos that connect through USB transceivers behave similar to generic Bluetooth mice, and that means that they are not necessarily plug and play like USB wired mice. A potential problem could arise if you try to remove the Bluetooth mouse with a command of the form bluetoothctl remove XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
